# How to have multiple versions of an application in visual studios

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

This is hopefully a simple question. I have an application written in vb.net using the visual studios 2010 environment. Every so often I want to make an offshoot of the application (many small changes to the code through the application). Currently my options are duplicating the entire application OR changing the code to allow me to make the choice of what I want to do at runtime. This is annoying an cumbersome. Any advice on how to do this a better way, or what setting I should turn on/use that all ready allows this would be great! Thanks!

Comment: what source control method do you use?  most allow branching and cloning

Comment: What kind of application is it? Website or Winforms or something else?

Comment: @Plutonix I think a source control method is what I'm looking for. Is there one built into VS2010?

Comment: @AdarshShah it's a Winforms application.

Comment: So are you using any source control at all?

Comment: @AdarshShah No. Is there any built into VS2010 that I can use easily? Or do I have to download an add on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visual studio online as a source control. Your code will be stored online and you can connect to it using Team Explorer. It free for upto 5 users.

http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs

Comment: So this will allow me to control multiple versions of my code? Is there a limit to the length of code or the number of versions?

Comment: Are you aware of source control at all? It is a source control so you can have different versions and history of your changes.

Comment: I've never used source control before. It looks like just what I was looking for though. Thanks a lot. I consider this question to now be answered!

Answer (score 1):

you best bet is to use a version control system as suggested.

alternatively, if you want to support multiple versions that are mostly the same for a long period of time you can look into pre-processor directives (not sure about vb.net but c# has them):

```
#ifdef feaure1
some code
#endif

#ifdef another-feature
some other code...
#endif
```

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg VB has this as a compiler directive, or `#CONST feature1` then you can do `#IF feature1 Then....`  makes the code hard to read, but nice for quick tests.